# How to properly render new elements after a POST request?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react page that looks like this:

[image: Page Hierachy]

and right now when creating a new category the post request goes through to the database but the categories is not rendered again to display the new category unless you refresh the page (GET request for all categories on page start up).

**SideBar.js**

```
  createNewCategory = async (input) => {
    console.log("CREATING NEW: ", input);
    var response = await fetch("http://localhost:8081/api/categories", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Token": 1234,
        Accept: "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        title: input
      })
    })
    let resp = await response.json();
    this.setState({
      categories: [...this.state.categories, resp]
    })
  }
```

**CreateCategory.js**

```
  handleNewCategory = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    this.props.createNewCategory(this.state.input)
    this.setState({
      input: ''
    })
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleNewCategory} className="new-category-form">
        <h4>Create Category</h4>
        <input onChange={this.handleInput} className="new-category-input" type="text" value={this.state.input} />
        <input className="new-category-input" type="submit" value="Create" />
      </form>
    )
  }
```

**CategoriesContainer.js**

```
function CategoriesContainer(props) {
  function renderCategories(){
    console.log("PROPS: ", props)
    return props.categories.map(category => {
      console.log("CATEACH: ", category)
      return <Category key={category.id} category={category} />
    })
  }

  return(
    <div>
      {renderCategories()}
    </div>
  )
}
```

At the moment if I create a new category with a name of letters I get the err

```
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token a in JSON at position 0 sidebar.js:46
```

and if I create it with numbers I get

```
Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.
```

Im still new to react so hopefully Im not completely off the mark here, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. First off I was using response instead of resp to update the state and I was returning just the name rather than the whole object to the POST request.